# How to show one column in bootstrap when there is one element but show two columns when there are two elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working with row class in bootstrap. The row has two columns. One is for x and one is for Y.
There are dynamic situations where there will be either X column or either Y column or both the columns inside the row. 
My query is since one row can have 12 columns, so when I have only X column then it will take col-md-12 and when there is X and Y boths the columns then X and Y will take col-md-6 and col-md-6 respectively inside the row.

Example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">x</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">y</div>
</div>
```

When only one element(X) from database comes then

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">x</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is the job of a backend application or a JavaScript templating engine, such as React or Angular. HTML doesn't have much in the way of logic mechanisms. You could do it with basic JavaScript, but it would get cumbersome if you have more than a few simple cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting just `col` class to all `div` it will auto adjust the width. However it will act same across all devices.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" style="background-color:red;">Div 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">Div 1</div>
      <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">Div 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```